# Login Incorrect in Ubuntu 16+ cloud-image

Tags: linux, login, cloud

I don't know why but I can't log in via "ubuntu" on cloud-image. Does anyone have an idea?

**What it gives:**

```
Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS ubuntu ttyS0

ubuntu login: ubuntu
Password: 

Login incorrect
ubuntu login: Ubuntu
Password: 

Login incorrect
ubuntu login: 
Login timed out after 60 seconds.

Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS ubuntu ttyS0

ubuntu login:
```

**Image config**

```
runcmd:
 - [ apt-get, -y, remove, cloud-init ]
passowrd: "1234"
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

**CLI install line**

```
sudo virt-install --import --connect=qemu:///system --name 3rdCloudChild --ram 2048 --vcpus=2 --os-type=linux --os-variant=ubuntu16.04 --disk CloudImage.img,device=disk,bus=virtio --disk config4.img,device=cdrom --graphic none --network bridge=virbr0,model=virtio
```

I tried some combinations with: "Ubuntu", "ubuntu", "root" password as 1234, "1234". Looked at the configs that are showing up. I think everything is fine, but still cant find an answer in the internet.

### Problem solved:

**First: I downloaded another version(22.04): but it will work with 16**

**Second: got guestfs-tools to get virt-customize option**

```
sudo apt install guestfs-tools -y
sudo virt-customize -a CloudImage.img --root-password password:1234
sudo virt-customize -a CloudImage.img --uninstall cloud-init
```

**Third: changed config to contain only those lines**

```
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

**Fourth: started server with credentials: root/1234 - successfully logged in**

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the config: `passowrd`

Comment: O M G, I love you. :D @GeraldSchneider

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a typo in the config: `passowrd`

Comment: OK, I thought this would help but still no. I continue to have the same problem. I changed the config at password to 1234 as well as "1234" but it still says the login is invalid. Ehh I was happy too soon